# Musical notes listener

Tags: windows, gratis, music-recognition

I'm looking for a gratis software for Windows that listens to free vocal musical notes that I produce and corrects me if I'm wrong.

For instance, if I produce `Re` instead of `Do`, the software will detect it as `Re` (it will detect the right musical note produced).